# max232 charge pump problem

Tags: voltage, capacitor, rs232, charge-pump, max232

I have a problem with my MAX232 chip and can't find the solution. The schematic of the chip is in the attachment. The chip is soldered on to a PCB.

I've checked all the connections, the supply voltage and the grounding. The supply voltage is a steady 5V signal and the ground pins of the caps and chip are correctly connected so I'm guessing that isn't the problem.

The strange thing that I found out is that the VS+ pin is 4,5V and the VS- pin is 0V instead of the 8.5V and -8.5V according to the datasheet.

How can this be possible or is the chip burned?

Thanks in advance.

[image: schematic]

Comment: datasheets suggests smaller capacitors. although it doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Are you using polarized capacitors and connecting them backwards?

Comment: Circuit looks fine. Check for shorts between pins due to soldering.

Comment: The capacitors are Nonpolarized ceramic wich according to the datasheet are acceptable. I've checked the pins for short circuit and found out that pin 14 is connected with ground. My guess is that it is internally connected due to a short circuit. Visually I couldn't find any short circuit due to soldering. I don't think that the problem is in the PCB layout because another PCB with this IC works fine.

Comment: Around two years ago I've had a similar and misterious issue with some MAX232. In my case they were also overheating. The only solution was to change supplier. Perhaps you've run into a bad batch as well. Upvoting, because I'm also interested in a definite answer to this.

Comment: If this is a Maxim MAX232, then Maxim Integrated tech support can help. If it's a defective chip or a counterfeit being sold with Maxim's brand mark then Maxim will definitely want to investigate. (*note: I am a Maxim applications engineer*) Output T1OUT should definitely not be grounded, that would explain the charge pump being undervoltage. Can you lift pin 14 from the PCB and confirm it really is an internal short to ground?

Comment: This is a chip from Texas Instruments. Before the weekend I ordered some new ones. If soldering a new chip on the footprint doesn't solve the problem, I will definitely contact Texas Instruments to find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I solderded a new IC on the footprint and my application is working again. The chip somehow must have been damaged due to wrong voltages or ESD I think.